# npm & node doesn't give any output

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, raspbian, apt

I wanted to install a package via npm, how i already did a few months ago... but somehow i get a response `"npm command not found"` but i haven't uninstalled it... same with node... `whereis node` does not show anything aswell... so i installed it again, `whereis node` outputs `node: /usr/bin/node /usr/sbin/node /usr/share/man/man8/node.8.gz /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz` but it doesn't work... i get no output as seen on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRW1M.jpg)

please help me fix this probably stupid misstake.

Answer (score 0):

Try re/installing node. NPM comes with node.

`$ sudo apt install nodejs`

If this is not working, try installing by using NVM (Node Version Manager). NVM is the recommended solution anyway.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: I allready tried that severall times... also with `apt purge node npm` and reinstalled it, rebooted... nothing works

Comment: found my error... i was logged in as root... and there was no npm installed for the root user... tried it again as actuall user and it worked...